# Using the same action several times with different parameters with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a problem with actions in React-Redux.
I'm trying to create a virtual store and I want to create a showcase containing a list of all products, and two more separated by brand, so I created an action with the "mark" parameter in the action.

```
export const getProductsByMark = mark => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch({type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTSBYMARK_REQUEST})

    const {data} = await Api.getRequest(`/api/products/mark/${mark}`)    
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTSBYMARK_SUCCESS,
      payload: JSON.parse(data),      
    })    
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTSBYMARK_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

But when I call the action on my home page multiple times, with different parameters, the element is repeated several times with the last request I passed

```
export const SetNikeProducts = () => {         
  const nikeDispatch = useDispatch() 
  const getProductsMark = useSelector(state => state.getProductsByMark)
  const { products: productsNike, loading: loadingNike, error: erroNike } = getProductsMark;    

  useEffect(() => {    
    nikeDispatch(listProductsMark('Nike'))
  }, [])

  return (
  productsNike.length != 0 || productsNike != undefined ?
    <div>
      <br></br>
      <h2 className="homescreen__title">Nike</h2>
      <div className="homescreen__products">
        {loadingNike ? (
          <h2>Loading...</h2>
        ) : erroNike ? (
          <h2>{erroNike}</h2>
        ) : (
          productsNike.map(product => (
            <Product
              key={product._id}
              name={product.name}
              description={product.description}
              mark={product.mark}
              price={product.price}
              discount={product.discount}
              imageUrl={product.imageUrl}
              productId={product._id}
            />
          ))
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
    
    :
    <div>Deu ruim</div>
  )
}
```

Exemplo:

SetNikeProducts
SetFilaProducts
SetAdidasProducts

Vitrine:

*Adidas Products
*Adidas Products
*Adidas Products

I tried to change the name of the dispatch multiple times but without success, I wanted to split the tags using the same controller function, to avoid having to create a controller for each tag.

Comment: A couple questions - Where are you dispatching `getProductsByMark`? What does your success reducer look like (i.e. where you store to `state.getProductsByMark`?